# angularjs responso from serrver passing all if statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on some app in AngularJs and Spring, and i've encountered a problem.

Response from backend:

```
["PPT", "PPU"]
```

and the function in angular controller:

```
function setCompanyCodes (companyCodes) {
    var tmpArray = [];
    var tmpObject = {
            value: "",
            name: ""
    };
    _.each(companyCodes, function (val) {
            tmpObject.value = val;
            if (val === "PPT") {
                tmpObject.name = "Post Patron Team";
            } else if (val === "PPU") {
                tmpObject.name = "Post Patron University";
            }
            tmpArray.push(tmpObject);
        }
    );
    $scope.companyCode = tmpArray;
}
```

The problem is that val passes both if statements, so it ends with two same names for companies. I've tried double equal sign - same result.

Comment: can you show what the output of console.log(val) is? Maybe you have to decode the array that you received from the backend back into JSON to  process it.

Comment: That seems that the elements in your array match both values. Check what you have in your companyCodes array.

Comment: output of console,log(val) - PPT ,and in second run PPU

Comment: Could you try using `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: @SadokMtir companyCodes is the response array from backend

Comment: @Mistalis I've tried, same effect

Comment: can you pls provide the console.log output of companyCodes before ._each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constantly using and pushing the same object, but you have to remember that an array/object is passed by reference and not by value, like a string for example.

Example:

```
var objArr = [];
var obj = {value: "",name: ""};
obj.value = "PPT";
obj.name = "Post Patron Team";
objArr.push(obj); //objArr: [{value: "PPT", name:"Post Patron Team"}]
obj.value = "PPU"; //objArr: [{value: "PPU", name:"Post Patron Team"}]
```

**How do you solve it?**

You can push a copy of the obj, which breaks the reference to the original object.

```
tmpArray.push(angular.copy(tmpObject));
```

Comment: Mistakes, and their solutions, only help to strengthen your knowledge.